# capture browser restore option

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

How I can capture browser restore/maximize event in jQuery or javascript? We can use window.onresize but that only tells that the browser is resized. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to determine this on script level.

You could - as a very unreliable workaround - compare the `window.width` and `document.clientWidth` properties after a `resize` event and see whether they match, or almost match. If they do, it's *possible* a `maximize` action has taken place.

I think it won't get any better than that, and even this method is subject to many, many factors. If there is a vertical toolbar, preventing the browser from resizing to the screen's full width, the values will differ, making it harder and harder to determine a resize event.